# UI is not updating the backing bean

Tags: jsf, cdi

This is my UI code in JSF. The app is a small currency conversion from Singaporean dollar to Japanese Yen.

```
<h:form>
            <h:inputText id="conversion" value="#{conversor.sgd}"></h:inputText>
         <h:commandButton value = "Convertir a yen">
            <f:ajax execute = "@all" render = "conversion_lista" event="click"/>
         </h:commandButton>
         <h2><h:outputText id = "conversion_lista" value = "Conversion: #{conversor.jpy}"/></h2>
      </h:form>
```

And this is my backing bean:

```
@Named("conversor")
@Dependent
public class Conversor { 

    private int sgd;

    public Conversor() {
        sgd = 1; //initial value
    }

    public int getSgd(){
        return sgd;        
    }    

    public void setSgd(int sgd){
        this.sgd = sgd;
    }

    public int getJpy(){
        return sgd * 2; //fake
    }
}
```

I want to click on the commandButton, execute the first inputText, make the `sgd` property in the backing bean change, then render the outputText by previously calculating the converstion from Singaporean dollar to Japanese yen.

However the input isn't passed to the backing bean.

I did try some things like, making `getJpy()` return a random number everytime it's called, and it did render a random number everytime I clicked the button. So that means that call works. But I can't pass the text input (sgd/singaporean dollar) to the backing bean and make the right conversion.

What's going on in here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it.

I used `@RequestScoped` instead of `@Dependent`.

I have no idea what I'm doing, but it works.

Now the outcome is what I wanted, the conversion takes place on the UI when I click the button.

Comment: _"I have no idea what I'm doing, but it works."_ Then start by reading some good basic tutorials